# C++ template parameter/class ambiguity

Tags: c++, templates, standards

while testing with different version of g++, the following problem came up

```
template<class bra>
struct Transform<bra, void> : kernel::Eri::Transform::bra {
        static const size_t ni = bra::A::size;
```

`bra::A` is interpreted as `kernel::Eri::Transform::bra::A`,  rather than template argument by g++ 4.1.2.  on the other hand, g++ 4.3 gets it right.

what should be correct behavior according to standard?

Meanwhile, I refactor slightly to make problem go away.

Comment: Even if 4.3 is doing the correct thing, it's probably a good idea to not duplicate names because you're going to confuse the hell out of those reading the code otherwise.

Comment: @Bil that was refactor part.  I am cleaning up some brainstorming activity

Comment: GCC4.5 is fixed and does it like 4.1, at least in my test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to me like gcc 4.1.2 was right. *§14.6.1/7 (ISO/IEC 14882, C++03)*:

> In the definition of a class template or in the definition of a member of such a template that appears outside of the template definition, for each base class which does not depend on a template-parameter (14.6.2), if the name of the base class or the name of a member of the base class is the same as the name of a template- parameter, the base class name or member name hides the template-parameter name (3.3.7).

Comment: thank you.   can you provide me with a link to standard?  I found April 19, 2000 rev.  is it good enough (it does address this particular issue)?

Comment: @aaa: I was referring to C++03, there should be a final draft online. See here for links etc.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents

Comment: I am always amazed when people are able to come up with the exact paragraph from the standard :p